How to completely uninstall and remove Ubuntu from PC
I tried to install Ubuntu using the download and instructions from:
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop#how-to-install
I downloaded ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso and then it created the folder:
Drive (F:) Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I downloaded balenaEtcher to create a bootable flash drive as stated in the instructions but it did not work.
Now I want to delete completely the ISO image file/folder and uninstall and perhaps start again. I cannot seem to just delete the folder or find a way to uninstall or remove it.
The attached image shows the folder structure on my PC.
Additionally, I want to completely remove any Linux/Ubuntu traces from my PC. I wonder whether my more recent difficulties installing Ubuntu are related to files from older versions.
Thanks


It looks like you have double clicked on the downloaded ISO file and mounted then twice. Right click on the F: Drive and click Eject. Repeat for the H: Drive. Then delete the file from the Downloads folder.

@karel are you sure OP has actually installed Ubuntu? They may have inadvertantly mounted the ISO file twice.

... the Linux "penguin" in the sidebar is likely an (unrelated) WSL installation. See for example Why do I have a "Linux" part in Windows 10 File Explorer?

This question is similar to: How to remove Ubuntu from dual boot system with Windows?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user68186, thanks i have removed it now.

@steeldriver, thank you. I had tried to completely uninstall wsl previously but this setting must have lingered on.

@DavidDE, thank you. I searched through previous questions to see if there was anything similar before posting but could not quite find what I was looking for. The post you refer to looks like it is related but i think the person seems to have a different problem and the main answers do not relate to the situation I had.

Right click on the "DVD Drive"s, and click on Eject/Unmount.

Then delete the ISO.

I took the screenshot for my answer, but you can have it.

Thank you for the edit. I did not have a windows machine around to take the screenshot.

Thank you. I had tried to look at "unmounting" the folder but could not find a way. I had also tried to "eject" one of the folders, but it did not quite work maybe because the actual dvd-drive does not work properly (my computer is quite old). I could not work out what was going wrong.
It has worked now and I am going to try again to install.
